# Does recursive partition of a graph using min-cut yield the minimum cumulative sum of edges weights?

Tags: graph-theory, igraph

Suppose I have an undirected graph with weigthed edges a and vertices.

I want to partition the graph in N subgroups. Suppose that any time a cut occurs, I sum the weights of the edges which belong to the cut in a cumulative sum called S.

I want to split the main graph in N subgroups so that S is minimum.

My question is: if I apply recursively the min-cut algorithm until I get N subgroups, is it guaranteed that S will be minimum?

As a further constraint, assume you cannot split subgraphs with less than D vertices.

Comment: What does this have to do with statistics?

Comment: Isn't graph theory also used in statistics?